# Calling a random record on pageload via PHP, dynamically displaying result via AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

this is something I've been stuck on for around 7 hours total over the last 3 days, and it is driving me absolutely insane. Any assistance you could lend me with be greatly appreciated.

Basically I want to:

1. Call a PHP function on pageload which randomly selects a record from
   my MySQL database
2. Dynamically display that record in a HTML page

(Once I've got that down, I also want to be able to trigger that this process on the click of a button.)

Before tackling this task, I put together a prototype which dynamically displays a specific record via a HTML dropdown menu: http://lrdondmt.com/week13/ajaxprototype1.html

I've been trying to modifications to this code to achieve the above.

My PHP looks like this:

```
<?php

// connect to database

    $username= "**withheld**"'
    $password="**withheld**";
    $database="**withheld**";
    $table="banddb";
    mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

// the query itself, selects random record from database

    $sql="SELECT * FROM banddb WHERE id >= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) FROM quotes ) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

// echo result

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo '<b>Band name:</b>&nbsp;' . $row['bandname'] . '</br></br>';
    echo '<b>Location:</b>&nbsp;' . $row['city'] . ',&nbsp;' . $row['state'] . '</br></br>';
    echo '<b>Image:</b> </br></br>' . '<img src="http://lrdondmt.com/discovermusic/images/' . $row['imgpath'] . '" />' . '</br></br>';
    echo '<b>About the band: </b>' . $row['abouttheband'] . '</br></br>';
    echo '<a href="' . $row['bandcamplink'] .  '"><img src="http://www.lrdondmt.com/discovermusic/images/bandcamp-icon.png" alt="Find on the band on Bandcamp" /></a>' . '</br></br>';
    echo '<a href="' . $row['facebooklink'] .  '"><img src="http://www.lrdondmt.com/discovermusic/images/facebook-icon.png" alt="Find on the band on Facebook" /></a>' . '</br></br>';
    echo '<b>Bandcamp player:</b> </br></br>' . '<iframe width="300" height="100" id=bandcampplayer src="http://bandcamp.com/EmbeddedPlayer/v=2/album=' . $row['bandcampid'] . '/size=grande/bgcol=e9e9e9/linkcol=890101/" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" >' . '</br></br>';
  }
echo "</table>";

// close connection 

mysql_close();

?>
```

My HTML document looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

    <title>AJAX prototype 2</title>

<script type="text/javascript" >    
    function showRecord()
    {
          {
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
          return;
          }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getmusic2.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function(showRecord))
    </script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="txtHint">
    <em>Your content should appear here.</em>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you need any further info, please just ask.

Comment: if it is possible, use jquery and life would be much simpler....

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using jQuery, you could replace your whole showRecord() function with this more simple jQuery function :

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'getmusic2.php',
     success: function(data) {
         $('#txtHint').html(data);
     }
});
```

Also, your on load call should look like that :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    showRecord();
});
```

Comment: +1 for noticing JQuery...didn't even see that or I would've suggested ```$.get()```

Answer (score 0):

Your closure looks wrong when calling your ajax function, fix this line

```
$(document).ready(function(showRecord))
```

to look like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){showRecord()})
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my error, much appreciated.

I ended up resolving this by using a different method to call the function on page load:

     <body onload="showUser()">

Comment: You should avoid putting javascript in your markup as much as possible...things get cluttered quickly that way and hard to debug later on.